# Recursividade em C: Somatório

Tags: c, funções, recursão

Estou aprendendo **Recursividade** em C e preciso fazer uma função recursiva que retorne o somatório de um número **n** qualquer.
O protótipo da função é `float somatorio(int n)` e o somatório a ser calculado tem a seguinte fórmula: **Σ (de i = 1 até i = n) {n / 1 + n}**

Então a minha dúvida é o seguinte: o **caso base é 1?**
    E quanto ao cálculo do somatório: Como definir? Acho que é algo que começa com:

```
float somatorio(int n){
  float i;
    if( n == 1){
            return n;
        }else{
            i = n;
            i = (n / 1 + n) + somatorio(); // o que viria dentro da segunda parte?   (1 + n)?
            return i;
        }
}
```

Definição do exercício: Endereço da imagem: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/imagem-png--304

Comment: Não entendi o que é essa divisão por 1, isso não faz sentido e porque tem que somar `n´ com `n`. Que somatório esse? Acho que este código deveria ter 2 linhas, quem sabe uma. Veja se é isso: http://ideone.com/Hcvn1D

Comment: Coloquei depois uma imagem com o enunciado do programa. Apesar disso, logo abaixo um usuário ajudou na elaboração do algoritmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim o caso base é 1.
O caso base é o caso mais simples e que você sabe qual é o valor de retorno para aquele caso. Esse é momento em que a sua função passa a retornar um elemento final para quem a chamou.
No seu problema o caso conhecido e mais simples é quando n = 1, já que todo o somatório neste caso terminará quando n for igual a 1, no seu problema temos que o somatório de 1 é n/(1+n) => 1/(2) => 0.5.
Então digamos que queiramos o somatório de 5 isso seria (5/6)+(4/5)+(3/4)+(2/3)+(1/2) correto?
podemos pensar também que o somatório de 5 é: 5/(1+5) + somatorio de 4.
se formos pensar que o somatório de 4 é 4/(1+4) + somatório de 3 e assim sucessivamente então teriamos que:
somatorio(5) = 5/(1+5) + somatorio(4)
somatorio(4) = 4/(1+4) + somatorio(3)
somatorio(3) = 3/(1+3) + somatorio(2)
somatorio(2) = 2/(1+2) + somatorio(1)
OPA! Nós sabemos que o somatório de 1 é 0.5 pois ele é o nosso caso base
asism então teriamos:
somatorio(2) = 2/(1+2) + 0.5 => 1.1666...
então sabemos que somatorio(2) = 1.1666, e agora podemos calcular o somatório de 3, de 4 e por fim de 5.

Escrevi um exemplo em código do algoritmo descrito acima para tentar demonstrar como ficaria.

```
# include <stdio.h>
/*Função recursiva (calcula o somatorio de n)*/
float somatorio(int n)
{   
/*Veja que meu caso base é o somatório de 1
    e retorno o resultado que eu ja sei somatorio(1) = 1*/
    if (n == 1)
    {   
        return 0.5;
    }   
    /*Se não for meu caso base então eu 
    calculo o somatório do meu antecessor e somo o meu valor*/
    else 
    {   
        return ((float) n/(1+n) + somatorio(n-1));
    }   

}   

int main()
{   
    //Imprimo o resultado do somatorio de 5
    printf("%f", somatorio(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer `\sum_{i=1}^n{ i \over 1 + i }`, que seria `return n / (n + 1.) + somatorio(n - 1);`, `somatorio()` retornando `double`. EDIT: O caso base retorna `0.5`, também...

Comment: @Wtrmute Exato. Verifiquei que o **caso base realmente é 0.5.** Quanto ao que você sugeriu, é exatamente isso. Então a função funcionando corretamente é essa:       `float somatorio(int n){
                if( n == 1){
                    return 0.5;
                }else{
                    return n / (1. + n) + somatorio(n - 1);
                }
    }`

Comment: @Wtrmute Porém ainda tenho uma dúvida: Porque no `else{ return n / (1. + n)` o número um tem que ser acompanhado do `.`(ponto decimal)?

Comment: @Mike entendi o seu problema agora haha, mas realmente o caso base ainda é o somatório de 1 e retorna 0.5 neste caso.
 Quanto ao . de '1.' é necessário pois em C uma divisão de dois números inteiros retorna um número inteiro, quando você coloca o ponto na verdade você está forçando o 1 a ser um número real e portanto a resposta será um valor real.

Ou seja em C:
3/2 = 1
3/2. = 1.5
3./2 = 1.5
3./2. = 1.5
(float) 3/2 = 1.5 
_Nesse último caso estamos utilizando o que conhecemos como cast, ou seja estamos especificando o tipo de resultado que é esperado pela operação.

Comment: @Mike: É como o WaGjUb mencionou; `1.` (ou `1.0`, se preferir) é um literal de tipo `double`, enquanto `1` é um literal de tipo `int` (`1.f` ou `1.0f` é de tipo `float`). Nós usamos esse literal de ponto flutuante para forçar o resultado da expressão para ponto flutuante.

Comment: Na verdade, a interpretação da resposta abaixo não está correta.
O somatório está definido pela fórmula. Portanto, sim, o somatório de 1  é mesmo 0,5, mas, o somatório de 2, ou seja soma(2) não é 1,1666... , mas 0,83, veja: 
soma(2) = 1/1+1 + 1/1+2 = 1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6 ou 0,8333..
Assim, soma(3) = 1/1+1 + 1/1+2 + 1/1+3 => 5/6 + 1/4 => 13/12 = 1,083333. 
Chegamos ao passo de indução:
soma(n) = soma(n-1) + 1/(n+1).
Dessa forma, a fórmula indutiva fica:
soma(1) = 0,5; (caso base) e
soma(n) = soma(n-1)+1/(1+n) (passo de indução).
Exemplo no link: https://repl.it/IpA5/6

Comment: @ed1rac na realidade a interpretação do problema foi baseada na fórmula apresentada pelo Mike que a define como: somatorio é n/(n+1) e não 1/(n+1) como você interpretou.

Comment: Ele colocou a definição do exercício na imagem. 
Veja:

 Endereço da imagem: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/imagem-png--304

Comment: Ele realmente não soube muito se explicar porque não tem muito conhecimento nem de recursividade nem de somatório. e a resposta dada não está correta!
O problema é de simples interpretação.

Comment: @ed1rac mas porque não está correta?  No codigo que você propos em repl.it/IpA5/6 você realiza o somatório com o numerador constante enquanto que no exercicio da imagem o numerador é também variável. Eu inseri meu código no seu link para que pudessemos comparar as diferenças pois realmente "o problema é de simples interpretação".

Comment: Vc tem razão. Basta alterar o numerador de um para n. Corrigirei logo mais.

Comment: Já alterei o programa. Vc tem perfeita razão, @WaGjUb 
Para simplificar as contas eu fiz o numerador ser um (por algum motivo inexplicável). Seu código estava correto. E o que fiz também.
Vou dar um like na sua resposta.  Perdão pelo atrapalho!

O novo link: https://repl.it/IpA5/9